# RRDTOOL - left-axis-format - 3-4 digit numbers not working

Tags: graph, format, label, rrdtool

My left axis is not formatting the numbers the way I want.
I have the range set as:

```
-l 400 -u 1400 -r
```

I want the numbers/labels on the left (Y) axis to look like

400, 500, ... 1000, 1100

Not 0.4 k, 0.5 k, .... 1.0 k, 1.1 k

If I put this format instruction in,

```
--left-axis-format %4.0lf
```

I get 0, 0, 1, ... 1, 1

```
--left-axis-format %4.1lf
```

I get 0.4, 0.5, ... 1.0, 1.1, ...

Answer (score 1):

Exponents. Took a bit to dig deeper into the manual.

```
--units-exponent 0 \
--left-axis-format %4.0lf \
```